# How to refresh and Reload the pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one requirement.i.e. Have one login form contains username and password,once we entered wrong password, it navigates to another page(Error message page) and I clicked the browser back button for previous page(login page).Now my page is refreshing,but I need page Reloading.Can you please help me how to reload the page.
Thanks.

Comment: u mean that u r not able to go back to previous page? The question isnt clear enough, u might get down voted..so make it more clear and elaborate.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reload the page'. Anyway when you go back with your Browser back button it will reload. What is the difference between refresh and reload (in your term)

Comment: "Now my page is refreshing,but I need page Reloading". I don't understand, please explain more in detail what you want to do and what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hello').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```